# Is there any way to avail of the WDS query "passage" feature via the Java APIs?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

The Watson Discovery Service Java APIs allow a consumer to specify:

- query
- aggregation
- count
- filter
- offset
- returnFields

via `com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.discovery.v1.model.query.QueryRequest.Builder`

There appears (as of version 3.8.0) to be no way to set `passages=true` though? Is this feature coming/planned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was that the feature wasn't supported until v4.0 of the Java client (released Sept 2017)

Feature is available now.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the query options inside the call.

Within the documentation showing what you need to do for it. You need to set the query_options inside the call query.Builder()

With cURL you will set:

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/query?version=2016-12-01&natural_language_query='collie'&passages=true"
```

With Java you'll need to set something like:

```
Discovery discovery = new Discovery("2016-12-01");
discovery.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1");
discovery.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}", "{password}");
String environmentId = "{environment_id}";
String collectionId = "{collection_id}";
String queryOptions = { "passages": true };

QueryRequest.Builder queryBuilder = new QueryRequest.Builder(environmentId, collectionId, queryOptions);
queryBuilder.query("{field}:{value}");
QueryResponse queryResponse = discovery.query(queryBuilder.build()).execute();
```

Obs.: Within the documentation says: **query_options** Specifies the parameters of the query.
In Java and Node, specify this as a query `string`.

See the query options table for information about the contents of the string or dictionary.
See the official reference [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/query-reference.html#structure-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sayuri. I'm afraid that (version 3.8.0 of) the Builder doesn't accept an options parameter: `public Builder(String environmentId, String collectionId)`. Prob worth mentioning that the response object doesn't expose the passages node either.

Comment: I'm not very good with Java, sorry :x But if we follow the cURL Example, display likes set inside the instance discovery... and Sure, but have, you can see Within the documentation. [Check](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/?java#queries)

Comment: Check my edit, I add other information. My experience with discovery was with Python